# angular 7 add html with binding after view init

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an issue here,
i want to add to my html this code

```
<dx-report-viewer [reportUrl]="reportUrl" height="800px">
   <dxrv-request-options [invokeAction]="invokeAction" [host]="hostUrl">
   </dxrv-request-options>
</dx-report-viewer>
```

but only after getting params from

```
self.queryParams = self.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {      
  if (params['id']) {        
       self.ReportId = params['id']; // (+) converts string 'id' to a number
       console.log(self.ReportId);
       self.reportUrl += "ReportId=" + self.ReportId;
  }
```

Because otherwise the url will be wrong ...
but i can't get it work is it because dx-report is a directive from an external library ?

If someone can help would be great !!

Comment: Could you invent a property, a flag? Then use `*ngIf="paramsAdded"` on the element? The element wouldn't be rendered until the flag is set, I think. But I'm just speculating.

Answer (score 0):

Create a property and default it to false:

```
paramsAdded: boolean = false;
```

Wrap the report element in a div using `*ngIf`:

```
<div *ngIf="paramsAdded">
    <dx-report-viewer [reportUrl]="reportUrl" height="800px">
       <dxrv-request-options [invokeAction]="invokeAction" [host]="hostUrl">
       </dxrv-request-options>
    </dx-report-viewer>
</div>
```

When the parameters are available set the property to true to render the report element(s):

```
self.queryParams = self.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {      
  if (params['id']) {        
       self.ReportId = params['id']; // (+) converts string 'id' to a number
       console.log(self.ReportId);
       self.reportUrl += "ReportId=" + self.ReportId;

       self.paramsAdded = true;
  }
```

Comment: Yeah but if my value change afterward ?

Comment: I'm trying right now but getting the error vendor.js:29766 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ngif' since it isn't a known property of 'ng-container'.
1. If 'ngif' is an Angular directive, then add 'CommonModule' to the '@NgModule.imports' of this component.
2. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("

<div class="content-block">
 <ng-container [ERROR ->]*ngif="paramLoaded">

Comment: @NgModule({
  imports: [
CommonModule,

DxReportViewerModule,
// DxReportDesignerModule,
          TranslateModule.forRoot({
            loader: {
                provide: TranslateLoader,
                useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
                deps: [HttpClient]
            }
        }),
    ],
  exports: [ ReportViewerComponent, TranslateModule, TranslatePipe],
  declarations: [ ReportViewerComponent ],
})
export class ReportViewerModule { }

Comment: You are using ngIf with a capital I? This is the more recent Angular 7, not AngularJS?

Comment: But my answer is speculative at the moment, and I cannot test anything, so it may end up disappearing.

Comment: Ye i m using 
    "@angular/core": "^7.2.4",

Comment: <ng-container *ngif="paramLoaded">
  <div id="fullscreen-container" >
<!-- <div id="fullscreen-container" [innerHtml]="reportContainerReady"> -->
  <dx-report-viewer [reportUrl]="reportUrl" height="800px">
        <dxrv-request-options [invokeAction]="invokeAction" 
        [host]="hostUrl">
        </dxrv-request-options>
    </dx-report-viewer>
  </div>
  </ng-container>

Comment: wtf i missed indeed the capital I

Comment: nha your solution is not working the request is send as soon as the page is render